# Missing application shortcuts

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, app-drawer

We got a generic Jellybean tablet, and some of the preinstalled apps (Chrome, Maps and others) do not appear in the app drawer for some reason.

They do appear in the Google Play list of installed apps, and in the included Apk Installer.

How can I create home screen shortcuts to these apps?

Comment: Is your Jelly Bean 4.1 or 4.2? And is the tablet totally stock Android, or does it have manufacturer customizations?

Comment: 4.1. It probably has some customization. (is there such a thing as stock Android?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 solutions for you:

1. You can use [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&hl=en) (or any similar) application to add launcher to any installed application (or Android Activity).
2. Not sure if it helps, but you can check your launcher's settings. There should be item "Hidden applications" (or similar).
3. Install and use another launcher.

Comment: QuickShortcutMaker didn't work (it claims to create the shortcut, but it's nowhere to be found). The launcher doesn't seem to have have settings. I have reset app preferences, and made sure those apps aren't disabled. Using another launcher is a potential workaround, but I'd have to research which one,

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, I've tried QuickShortcutMaker - it works fine on 2.3 and 4.1. Just add widget and select needed activity - very easy. About new launcher: try Apex Launcher - it's similar to default Trebuchet but much powerful.

Comment: OK, I got QuickShortcutMaker to work.